# Is there any way of detecting how many requests finished within curl_multi_exec loop?

Tags: php, loops, curl

Using `curl_multi_*`,I want to execute a piece of code every x requests, is there any way of doing so?

The only way I came up with is to check the `$still_running` variable from `curl_multi_exec`, unfortunately, it doesn't work(it's inconsistent, sometimes it jumps from 7 to 1 without going through 6, 5, etc..)

Here's the code I came up with(it doesn't always work, as I said `$still_running` is inconsistent):

```
    $still_running = null;
    $callbackExecuted = 1;//Counts how many times callback function was executed.

    //execute the handles
    do
    {
        //Execute callback every 5 requests
        if ($numberOfRequests - $still_running === 5 * $callbackExecuted)
        {
            callback();
            $callbackExecuted++;
        }

        curl_multi_exec($mh, $still_running);
    } while ($still_running > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, curl_multi_exec() drives N transfers in parallel and for every invoke it drives them a little bit further. The $still_running counter is then how many of the transfers that are still in progress when curl_multi_exec() returns. And it will potentially require hundreds (or more) of invokes to finish a transfer - or more transfers.

If you want to act on when a transfer is completed, then you can see how $still_running is deducted as they are completed, or you can use [curl_multi_info_read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php)() to really see when each transfer is done.

Finally: your code example needs attention!! Due to the lack of a call to [curl_multi_select](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php)(), this program will busy-loop like crazy and spend 100% CPU time until all transfers are done. That's not a very nice thing.